# Change the container background for each slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have a slider with the following structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <p>Slide1 Content</p>
    </div>        
    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <p>Slide1 Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The wrapper width is 100% but the slide divs have a max-width in pixels (ie. 400px).
Is there a way to change the background of wrapper for each slide? I mean for example when the first slide is active, the wrapper background turns to yellow and when the second slide is active, the wrapper background turns to red.
As I know, there is no way to do this using CSS. So is it possible to do it using jquery?
I tried `.wrapper:has()` selector but it doesn't work the way I expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(".wrapper:has(#slide1)")) {
        $(".wrapper").css("background-color","yellow");
    } else if($(".wrapper:has(#slide2)")) {
        $(".wrapper").css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```

It turns the background to yellow, because the wrapper belongs to both slides.
Do you have any idea how to get it to work the way I want it to?

Note: I'm not the writer of the slider plugin, So I can't change the whole slider codes. I just want to do a few customization to meet my needs.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ua8bt6tk/)

Comment: What's the plugin are you using (your fiddle doesn't have any slider functionality)? First, check with the browser inspector tool what change in the DOM when a slide is active (some class is added t its div, another div appears, etc.).

Comment: @A. Iglesias I'm using [fractionslider](http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/). You may check the demo in the official website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the plugin demo with the browser inspector, it looks like when a slide is active, the plugin adds the class `active-slide` to the slide `div`.

Also in the documentation shows that in the plugin activation you can configure callbacks to execute on different events (http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/plugin-options-reference/). So put the background color change inside of the corresponding callback. Something like (check all the callbacks, to verify where you want to apply it)...

```
function setActiveSlideBackground() {
    var activeSlideId = $('div.slide.active-slide').attr('id');
    if (activeSlideId == 'slide1')
        $('div.wrapper').css('background','yellow');
    else if (activeSlideId == 'slide2')
        $('div.wrapper').css('background','red');
}

$('.slider').fractionSlider({
    'nextSlideCallback': function(el,currentSlide,lastSlide,step) {
        setActiveSlideBackground();
    },
    'prevSlideCallback': function(el,currentSlide,lastSlide,step) {
        setActiveSlideBackground();
    }
});
```